# When using luigi to build hadoop job pipeline, how to debug my task?

Tags: luigi

I am using [luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) as hadoop job pipeline. I read the example and docs, but can't find how to debug my script before I push the jobs to the hadoop servers?

More specific, I need to process a big set of data, and the run time is long, I prefer to test the jobs in small test data set rather than run it in the real data set.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial thing as far as I can tell, since what you want to debug is the actual Hadoop-integration. Maybe there is a way to mock or simulate a hadoop system ... or just install a minimal hadoop on your machine?

We do something similar for cluster tasks. We are executing commands through a convenience method that allows us to switch between running commands locally or through the HPC system by just switching the value of a parameter. You can see the code for this here, if you are interested:
https://github.com/samuell/sciluigi/blob/d403b1d04779fcb9d4d949cd2e554a892c86a67d/sciluigi/slurm.py#L99-L113

Comment: good job! Thanks for sharing!   We use luigi to deploy hadoop streaming jobs. Before we change to luigi, we test our script locally use system pipeline to pass the output of mapper to reducer. I think a similar method is better than we run job in hours and then find there is a bug.